# Replace name custom post type in URL by category name - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have this code to show in the page category.php every post of the category that want to see:

```
<?php

      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'trailers',
        'cat' => $category_id
      );
      $loop = new WP_Query($args);
      if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 


            $attachment_id = get_field('imagen1');
            $size = "custom-poster"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );

          ?>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 lastImageHome">
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
              <p class="movieTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
            </div>

          <?php


        endwhile; 
      endif;
```

But the_permalink of every post show me the URL of the custom post type. I would want to show in the  URL the name of the category that I chose instead of the name of the custom post type. For instance:

Current URL: http://web.com/trailers/post-movie

I wish the URL: http://web.com/horror/post-movie

How can I customize the URL of the_permalink ?

Any Idea ?

Comment: Are you trying to link to the category archive instead of the post, or are you trying to include a category base in the post URLs instead of the post type?

Comment: Currently my post show the post URL. That post has a category. When I want to show the link with the name of category instead of the name of the custom post type. The post belongs to a Custom post type but also it belongs to a category.

Comment: So it sounds like you're trying to replace the post_type base of "trailers" in all trailer posts with a category name instead. There are reasons that this is not done, the biggest of which is that a post can have multiple categories or you could add/remove or change those categories down the road. Am I understanding your situation correctly?

Comment: I thought that I could change the URL base with the category. So, is better create some custom post type like horror, thriller , etc. and create post inside those custom post type ?

Comment: That's an option, but it would be very hard to maintain. They are much better suited to categories. Why do you need the category in the URL of each post?

Comment: I will give you an example: if I had a lot of posts, in a custom post type, my URL would be: "web.com/name_custom_post_type/name_post", but If my post had a category called movies, I would like that my URL was web.com/movies/name_post. It's like a segment my posts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180828/discussion-between-johnnyd23-and-user3810167).